# Yii2: Highlight Row in gridview based on db column value

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a listing page where I display email lists and if I want to delete any list I do not actually delete it but it is marked as deleted in the table column.
For the `email_lists` I am using the GridView widget for displaying the lists and I want to highlight a row if it is marked as deleted in the table `email_lists`.

Any idea how can I highlight the whole row instead of column?

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'name',
        'total_recipients',
        'list_type',
        // 'is_deleted',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header' => 'Actions',
            'template' => '{update}{view_list}{delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'view_list' => function($url, $data, $key) {
                    return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>', ['/promos/promolistemails/index', 'id' => $data->id], ['title' => 'View List Emails']);
                },
                'update' => function($url, $data, $key) {
                    if ($data->list_type == 'custom') {
                        return Html::a('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>', '#.', ['title' => 'Edit List Emails', 'data-url' => yii\helpers\Url::to(['/promos/promolists/update', 'id' => $data->id]), 'class' => 'edit-list']);
                    } 
                },
                'delete' => function($url, $data, $key) {
                    if ($data->list_type == 'custom') {
                        return Html::a('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', $url, ['title' => 'Delete List', 'data-method' => 'post', 'id' => 'delete-list']);
                    }
                },
            ]
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i need to use the `rowOptions` for the GridView

```
'rowOptions'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $grid){if($model->is_deleted){return ['class'=>'red'];}},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
'rowOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $grid){
    if($model->is_deleted){
        return ['class' => 'danger'];
    }
},
```